# Is it possible to put Geoserver behind a proxy and access the WMS/WFS using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I just start to work with Geoserver and Openlayers and one of the main concerns of the project now is do not expose the geoserver web interface outside of the internal network. No access to `www.mydomain.com/geoserver/`

However the application that is available in the Internet needs to get data (wms/wfs) from the GeoServer. This all through OpenLayers.

Is this possible?

Comment: The short answer is yes. I can't help you with a long answer, because the way we are doing it is a custom proxy that also handles our AAA needs. But basically it is all HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, follow the instructions at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/software/java.html but instead of /geoserver use /geoserver/wms and /geoserver/wfs

Comment: Link broken, solution lost... :S

Comment: @iant Hi there, inf3rno is right, link is broken.

Comment: 5 years is a long time :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can have an apache httpd as frontend listening on port 80 with proyxing rewrite-rules (see mod_rewrite and mod_proxy) mapping /whateverurl on apache  to /geoserver/wms on the geoserver running on another tcp port.

Se more: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

you can setup a reverse proxy. Then point OL to it like a normal url.  I know you're not using ESRI but they have a guide online to [setup a reverse proxy](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=32634) that would apply to your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at these two project, maybe they can help you:

- [GeoShield](http://code.google.com/p/geoshield/)
- [GeoPrisma](http://geoprisma.org/site/index.php)

Comment: GeoShield looks like unmaintained.